# How to customize a node--type.html.twig template?

Tags: 8, theming

I activated the devel and devel kint modules. I also activated twig debugging, so, I can know which are templates used by Drupal.

So, I created a content-type named album that contains a field named tracks.

Now, I want customize this content type, so I created `node--album.html.twig` in templates folder of bartik, which works so I can begin to customize this template.

Now, I have to know which are variables used by this template. In comment section of `node--album.html.twig` I can read that `content` variable can be used to display content of page. I also read I can use subset of content, such as content.field_example to display a field.

OK, so if I want to modify rendering of field_tracks I can use `content.field_tracks`. Before using this variable I wanted to know all content variable, so I've written `[[ kint(content) ]]` in content section of this file. I rebuilt the cache, and I seen that content is an array, not an object as suggested in comment section of node file.

So, if I print `[[ content.field_tracks ]]` it returns nothing.

If I use `kinkt()` without parameters it breaks drupal and point me to core/install.php.

The same as I use `d()` without parameters.

At this point I am confused: there is a way to modify node--type twig templates without creating a file for each field?

Comment: `[[ ]]` is not valid twig syntax, you need to use curly brackets `{{ content.field_tracks }}`. Make sure you flush the cache to see changes. Alternatively, this should also work `{{ node.field_tracks.value }}`

Comment: You also don’t want to cherry pick through values in the render array, let it render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some examples

Render the whole field markup

```
{{ content.field_text }}
```

Get just the value of the field

```
{{ content.field_text.value }}
```

Get a field value from authors object

```
{{node.uid.entity.field_gender.value}}
```

For field above you can get the machine name of the field as you see it for example in `admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields`

For multivalue fields look at some examples [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208723/iterate-through-multiple-value-content-field-in-twig-template)

Read more about how to find more variables [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/discovering-and-inspecting-variables-in-twig-templates)