Upgrading filters to work with Twig 3 in Drupal 10.3
We had a custom content type in our Drupal 9.5 site with accordions. In the twig template we used to filter out content that was only suitable for display using the following filter.
{% for key,item in content.field_item_cards|filter(key|first != '#') %}

Now after upgrade to Drupal 10.3 we found that the filters are not working correctly. We used the following but it is not displaying anything
    {% for key,item in content.field_item_cards|filter(v => key is defined and key|first != '#') %}

I feel that the issue is either due to Twig 3 upgrade that happened with the upgrade to Drupal or change in the content type stucture.

You don't have a variable v and the arrow function receives the key as a second argument:
{% for key, item in content.field_foo|filter((item, key) => key|first != '#') %}


BTW your code example for Drupal 9 is not working for Drupal 9 either. It's already modified halfway. You probably had to change the code because of an if statement in the loop, like in this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/208765/47547.
D9 Twig code:
{% for key, item in content.field_foo if key|first != '#' %}

The if statement in loops was removed from Twig 3.x. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3256890
